# iOS development - Creating multiple draggable images

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I understand how to make a single image draggable, but I can't seem to make two different images draggable. This is the code I have:

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

  if ([touch view] == player1) {
      player1.center = location;
  } else {
      player2.center = location;
  }

}
```

player1 and player2 are my two images.

I don't understand why the above code does not work? I'd greatly appreciate any help/advice anyone could give me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is subclass `UIImageView` and implement `touchesMoved:` there. So when you Initialize your draggable view they both inherit the `touchesMoved:` Functionality. Your code should look more like this...

```
//Player.h
@interface Player : UIImageView

CGPoint startLocation;

@end

//Player.m
@implementation Player

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {   
     // Retrieve the touch point
     CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
     startLocation = pt;
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

       CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
       CGFloat dx = pt.x - startLocation.x;
       CGFloat dy = pt.y - startLocation.y;
       CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.center.x + dx, self.center.y + dy);
       self.center = newCenter;
}

@end
```

Now when you initialize your `Player`'s, example below:

```
Player *player1 = [[Player alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"player1.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:player1];
// You can now drag player1 around your view.


Player *player2 = [[Player alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:player2];
// You can now drag player2 around your view.
```

Assuming you're adding these `Players` to your `UIViewController`'s view.

They both implement `-touchesMoved:`

Hope this helps !

**UPDATE**: Added `-touchesBegan:` with full example of Dragging a subclass `UIImageView`, ensure you set the `.userInteractionEnabled` property to **YES** as this is **OFF** by default.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response!

The "/* your dragging code here */" part, do I still want the if statements in there?

Comment: I added more to the example, this should get you going with Dragging your Player around. If my solution is sufficient as the answer to your problem, please mark it off as such. :)

Comment: I really appreciate the lengths you have gone to, to assist me; however, I am still not clear. In the code you have provided there are no references to the images. When calling the Player class do I then include them?

Comment: `player1` and `player2` are your Images in my example. I'll edit it to reflect actual image files if that helps understanding.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I initialised the Player class in the viewDidLoad method, was this wrong? One of the images loads onto the screen, but is not draggable.

Comment: Did you make sure you set `player1.userInteractionEnabled = YES` ?

Comment: I forgot to do that, my bad!

Everything works now, I really appreciate all your help. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

`if ([[touch view] isEqual:player1])` because you comparing objects, not primitive scalars.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response!

Unfortunately, that still doesn't work though.

Comment: Try `[(UIView *)touch.view setCenter:location]` instead of `if` statement. And I'd suggest that you iterate through all touches, because `anyObject` only returns one, and that one can be outside your image.